# In Android Studio the action "Find Usages" by View ID in XML layout doesn't work with Android View Binding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewbinding

The [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) in Android is heavily advocated as a better replacement for `findViewById()` and even Kotlin extensions, but for some reason the most basic functionality as searching usages of a `View` by its ID in Layout Editor in Android studio doesn't work.

It doesn't work even in the [View Binding Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/ViewBindingSample) in the official Acrh Components Samples repository.
Here we have:

1. Xml layout `fragment_blank.xml` with a `TextView` with ID `textViewFragment` as following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".InflateFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

2. Fragment `InflateFragment.kt` which sets text to this `TextView` using view binding:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        fragmentBlankBinding = binding
        binding.textViewFragment.text = getString(R.string.hello_from_vb_inflatefragment)
        return binding.root
    }
```

3. So, when I select this ID in the layout editor and do action "Find Usages" from the context menu:
   [image]
4. Nothing actually gets found, but we clearly see that we are setting text to this text view in `InflateFragment.kt`
   [image]

Any ideas on how to make such usages searchable by `View` ID from the Layout Editor?
Can't believe that such a basic functionality is missing for View Binding.

Android Studio ver `4.0.1`.
Gradle ver `6.6.1`.
Android Gradle Plugin ver `4.0.1`

Comment: also wait for solution for a long time. have you tried AS preview versions?

Comment: Hi You can goto the generated file code and find use from there , I have written a blog post completely explaining view binding , you can use it to find the code path .checkout [Androidbites|ViewBinding](https://chetangupta.net/viewbinding/)